# special characters replacement in a php to mysql insert script

Tags: php, mysql, character

I am sorry if this has been asked before but I'm not understanding most of the stuff I've found using google. I'm just learning how to do this all so please bear with me.

I've created a working "INSERT" php script to insert data into a mysql 5.x database, it works without problem, however the issue i AM having is if the user puts a word with a ' or " into the fields the script spits back a "Error inserting new record" at the user. I need to know how to make the script automatically replace the ' with a \' before it tries to insert the information to a database.

What I have at the moment is....

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

include('../connect/connect-mysql.php');

$Colorist = $_POST['Colorist'];
$Active = $_POST['Active'];

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO colorist (Colorist, Active) VALUES ('$Colorist', '$Active')";

if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert)) {
    die('error inserting new record');
    }//end of nested if statement
$newrecord = "New record added";

} //end of main if


?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="insertcolorist.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
<fieldset>
<legend>New Colorist Data</legend>
<table border="1" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse">
<tr><th colspan="2"><font face="Verdana" size="2">Colorist Data</font></th></tr>
<tr><th><font face="Verdana" size="1"><label>Colorist: </label></font></th><td><font size="1" face="Verdana"><input type="text" size="150" name="Colorist" /></font></td></tr>
<tr><th><font face="Verdana" size="1"><label>Is the Colorist Active: </label></font></th><td><font size="1" face="Verdana"><select size="1" name="Active"><option value="">Select...</option><option value="Yes">Yes</option><option value="No">No</option></option></select></font></td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="add new colorist" />
</form>
<?php
echo $newrecord // New record added statement added at the top
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: also the font tag has been deprecated for an age...

Comment: no i dont want to prevent something, this is for my own use (and a couple friends who are helping me) to populate my databse easier... I dont want to PREVENT an entry, I want to make it so that  ' or " dont PREVENT me from doing it cause I will also use this information on another insert script i have that includes inserting blocks of text with speech quotes in it

Comment: the `'` and `"` characters are used in sql, your basically SQL injection yourself, which is BREAKING your query. PREVENTing sql injections will FIX the issue your having.

Answer (score 0):

There's a mysqli function for cleaning input string. It's as easy as use

```
$Colorist = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Colorist']);
$Active = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Active']);
```

This should be enough for the most common problems of this type

Comment: and this would go where i have  $Colorist = $_POST['Colorist']; ? or is it on a separate area, cause I tried it on that line and it didn't work

Comment: My fault, sorry, forgot an argument:
`$Colorist = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['Colorist']);
$Active = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['Active']);`
And yes, it would go on the same line where you now set $Colorist

Comment: ok this worked perfectly for THIS script, but I tried to implement it on another insert script of the exact same type ( only difference is the # of fields and where it inputs the data, it created a empty record.

`include('../connect/connect-mysql.php');
 
   $Power = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, ['Power']);
 
 $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO powercat (Power) VALUES ('$Power')";`

Comment: Does this code `['Power']` not fail you? won't you need `$_POST['Power']`?

Comment: AHA thats what messed up, thanks @_@ dunno how I lost that... it musta got missed int eh find/replace.. i greatly appreciate your help